# Can't assign char to array in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal

There is listing of procedure

```
var
  A, B: array [1..5] of String;
  Ch: Char;
begin
  A[1] := 'Hello Kitty';
  Ch := A[1, 1];
  B[1, 1] := A[1, 1];
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Line `Ch := A[1, 1]` works great, but `B[1, 1] := A[1, 1]` doesn't. What can be the problem?

Comment: I find A[1, 1] confusing on a one dimensional array, why does it even compile? A[1][1] is more demonstrative.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, because it is such a syntax for multidimensial arrays in pascal

Comment: @DenisBabarykin: Yes, it's syntax for a multi-dimensional array, but both `A` and `B` are **single-dimensional** arrays, so the syntax is inappropriate.

Comment: @Ken and Sertac: but it seems to compile, because `[a, b]` and `[a][b]` are functionally and syntactically equivalent. It is a bit confusing, but allowed.

Comment: @Rudy: Whether `[a,b]` and `[a][b]` are functionally equivalent is immaterial. They're both irrelevant, as both `A` and `B` are single-dimensional arrays. And apparently they're not syntactically correct, as the poster has said that `B[1, 1] := A[1, 1]` doesn't work (whatever *doesn't work* means, because that is not a problem description that is meaningful). There's no point in using multi-dimensional array syntax on a single-dimension array, whether it compiles or not - it's confusing and wrong.

Comment: @KenWhite, the syntax is ok, but the poster gets a range error when accessing a string index out of bounds, since B[1] is an empty string.

Comment: The biggest problem is that "doesn't work" omits the detail of how the code fails.

Comment: @Ken: **no, that these forms are functionally equivalent is not irrelevant**. A "multi-dimensional" dynamic array is **also just a single-dimensional array** (but of dynamic arrays instead of strings). In both cases you have a single dimensional array of something indexable, and in both cases you can use `[a, b]`. **That the second dimension is either a dynarray or a string doesn't make a big difference**. The second dimension could even be a static array or a ShortString, BTW.

Comment: @Ken: as LURD said, the **syntax** is not the problem. That "works", and I explained why. The problem is accessing the first element of an empty string. FWIW, in the very olden days (up to TP4 or even later, IIRC), the `[a][b]` (C-like) syntax **was not allowed**.

Comment: @Rudy: Did I post an answer saying that the syntax was the problem? No. I pointed out that the syntax was inappropriate, because the arrays are **not** multi-dimensional. Because something compiles doesn't make it correct. I don't know what your sudden interest is in harping at every comment I post lately, but it's getting rather annoying.

Comment: @KenWhite: You posted a **comment** saying the syntax was problematic. You wrote, in reply to me: "And apparently they're not syntactically correct". And the syntax is not inappropriate, no more than for dynamic "multi-dimensional" arrays, which are **single-dimensional** arrays (of arrays instead of strings) too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When executing the line:

```
B[1, 1] := A[1, 1];
```

you get a range error or an access violation.

This is because the `B` is an array of a managed type, which is initialized by the compiler with empty strings (each equal to nil).

The range error means that you are trying to access a string element out of bounds, i.e. `B[1,1]` (or `B[1][1]`). It will appear if the compiler option "Range checking" is on. Otherwise you get the access violation, since you are accessing a memory area that is not allocated.

---

To get it working, do something like:

```
B[1] := A[1,1];  // Or B[1] := A[1][1];
```

Comment: Or `B[1] := A[1][1];`

Comment: I'd expect him to do: B[1] := A[1], i.e. string to string. You can do Char to string too, of course. Or `SetLength(B[1], Length(A[1])); B[1, 1] := A[1, 1];`.

Comment: You won't get a range error but an access violation (which arguably is a kind of range error too). The reason you get that error, is because Delphi uses a nil for empty strings. Normally you would be able to write at least one character past the end of a string, because there is an implied `$0` character (for PChar compatibility). For empty strings that's not the case. `s:='';s[1]:='a';` will give you an AV at address 00000000, while `s:='a';s[2]:='b';` will not raise an exception at all. In any case, the problem is the same: writing in a place where you shouldn't.

Comment: @GolezTrol, In my Delphi 10.3 Rio, there is a range error. Also for your example. (With range error on). And in Delphi XE2 as well.

Comment: Without range error active, you will get the access violation, because of accessing an invalid address.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I probably had range checking of (in Seattle, btw). The range checking is indeed the first line of defense there. Only after that, the behavior is distinctly different between empty and non-empty strings.